# Load and Entry Adress of Kernel and Uboot

Tags: kernel, ram, bootloader, boot, u-boot

how the second stage bootloader knows which address it should load the uBoot and how uBoot knows where to load Kernel.

1- Do we give these address information through config files or device tree?

2- How do we find these addresses?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

So, when the hardware loads U-Boot, the address is SoC specific, and documented by that SoC in their manuals.  U-Boot will be configured at build time to know this location and be linked there.  Typically this is a two stage process with "U-Boot SPL" being loaded first and "U-Boot" proper being loaded by SPL.  Similar logic is used here to know a valid starting location to run at.  For the kernel and related portions, this is documented at https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/environment.html#image-locations for the common case and needs to take in to account both SoC specific things such as where DDR is mappped in address space as well as the typical constraints of the OS image in terms of size and alignment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Uboot and Kernel are loaded to RAM and RAM is another IC independent from SOC, how can SOC determine it? Every Ram has different Address( I assume ).

Comment: It all comes down to where the SoC (and it's documentation) says that it will map different peripherals.  Setting aside FPGA cases, all of these things are tightly coupled and the "magic address range" for each component is documented somewhere in the SoC manually.  Typically there's a dedicated address map table fairly early on in the documentation.